# Add external QML module path to QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: qt, module, cmake, qml

I have an external [QML module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-topic.html) composed of graphical elements. I'd like to find its path in order to add it to my `QQmlApplicationEngine`. Is there a way to do this?

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

engine.addImportPath("externalQmlModulePath");
```

With this, I'll be able to `import` the graphical elements from my `qrc`'s `QML` files (which are of course inside the project).

Comment: So you have a QML module, but you don't know where it is?

Comment: I do, but it's outside the project and may vary from one PC to another (we are several developpers on it). This is why I don't want to use an absolute path. I've been thinking about adding the module directory in my CMake file. Could that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`QStandardpaths`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html). Having your resources (whether your own or 3rd party) relative to those paths makes them consistently available on target systems. The suggested path for application specific data is `QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation`.

In CMake you could add a custom post-build command to copy all your resources (again, no difference if your own or 3rd party):

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${MY_APP} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${MY_APP_RES_SOURCE_DIR} ${MY_APP_RES_DEST_DIR})
```

## Edit

`QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation` is of course just an enum value to specify which standard path you are looking for. To actually get the app data path, use the [`standardLocations`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#standardLocations) method like this:

```
auto appDataPath = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation).first();
```

Finally, add your app's resource folder as import path (as you already did) and you're done:

```
engine.addImportPath(appDataPath + "/res_dir_name");
```

**Note:** On Mac you can get away more easily by putting resources in the application bundle.

Comment: The path that I need is the `last()` of the list, not the `first()`. How is that decided?
Note that `appDataPath` finishes with a `data` folder: `D:/workspace/bin/APPLICATIONS_xx_qt/Release/data`. It automatically finds the build type (`Release`) and creates a `data` folder. 

Therefore, here's my final `CMake` command:

`ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E COPY_DIRECTORY ${QML_COMPONENTS_DIR} ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/data)`

Comment: Hmm.. the docs say that the path list is sorted by priority. I guess that's just another platform specific thing we have to watch out for.